# JAVA and PHP on same server

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat

There is an index.html file which has two links in it.
    link1
    link2

Now Link1 navigates user to Helloworld.php and Link2 navigates to Helloworld.java.

Is it possible to host such an application on same server(it doesn't matter if two different ports are used). Also Apache and Tomcat don't need to talk to each other 
    Here we have Tomcat  for Java and Apache for PHP

Comment: As in have `PHP` and `JSP` as your back-end technologies? If they are listening on two different ports, it should be possible.

Comment: @anthony Forloney : Yes exactly . I don't need to access a java object from php or vice versa .

Answer (score 0):

yes.

If they are two different filenames then you just have to make sure that each interpreter (java / php) looks at the correct file.

Comment: can you elaborate a little .

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with [Apache Tomcat Connectors](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html) `mod_jk`, all you need to do is configure [workers.properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) once `mod_jk` is enabled with Apache.

Have your java application running on Tomcat or any Java supported server. Have your php application running in Apache (with mod_jk enabled and configure worker.properties to create external link to your java application)

Comment: which server should i use If it is tomcat , then what about php